# Sorting subset of indices according to some criteria

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

Consider

- a vector of the first n natural numbers, I, I=[0, 1, ...n-1], n<=32.
- another vector of naturals, S, S[i]<=2000, for any i=0..n-1, not necessarily unique
- a subset of I with m elements, J, 0 <= J[j] < n, for any j=0...m-1

Is it there an **efficient** way (in terms of CPU cycles/cache friendliness/memory) to sort the elements of J according to S(J)?

C++ code which uses standard algorithms are preferred.

Example:

```
I     = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
S     = [10, 50, 40, 20, 30]
J     = [1, 3, 4]
S(J)  = [50, 20, 30]
J sorted according to S(J) = [3, 4, 1]
```

I've considered working with std::multimap, to get the sorting for 'free', but the machinery behind std::multimap (allocations, etc) seems expensive.

Using std::pair to bind J and S(J) would allow using std::sort. The downside is that extra memory and an extra loop is needed to get the final sorted J.

My take is to sort both J and S(J) simultaneously using S(J) as a criteria in a hand written sort routine. However, writing a sort function in 2019 seems awkward.

Is it a clever way to do this? Is it possible to exploit the fact that n<=32?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My take is to sort both J and S(J) simultaneously using S(J) as a criteria in a hand written sort routine. However, writing a sort function in 2019 seems awkward.

You are on the right track, but you don't need to write your own sort.  You can leverage a lambda to get the custom sorting behavior you want while still using `std::sort` to sort the array for you.  What you'll do is take the values supplied to the lambda and use them as indexes into `S` and the comparing those results. That would give you code like

```
int main() 
{
    int S[] = {10, 50, 40, 20, 30};
    int J[] = {1, 3, 4};
    std::sort(std::begin(J), std::end(J),[&S](auto lhs, auto rhs){ return S[lhs] < S[rhs]; });
    for (auto e : J)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
3 4 1
```